# Service worker registering just fine on Firefox but not on chrome

Tags: javascript, proxy

I was making a proxy website using an open source project called [Ultraviolet](https://github.com/titaniumnetwork-dev/Ultraviolet-Node) It worked fine on localhost but when I tired it on my VPS it didn't work then I realized it required SSL so I made it SSL and it works fine on Firefox but on chrome it shows this in the console:

```
An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://mydomain/service/') with script ('https://mydomain/sw.js'): An unknown error occurred when fetching the script.
```

I have tried changed the certificate for SSL but that didn't really fix it and tried using cloudflare instead of digitalocean for handling the DNS but that also didn't fix it, hosting the same app on something like repl.it works fine on both chrome and Firefox.

Edit: also going to the script location itself using either Firefox or chrome shows the script code

Comment: I'm having the same error. Did you fix?

Comment: It's been a while but I think the fix was to use SSL, and for some reason it only worked on Google Chrome, not FIrefox though.

Comment: Can confirm. Google Chrome needs SSL and HTTPS to work